# SQLite Query returns null

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

**What I've done**

---

I have a Gridview which is filled over my Database with the imageID's. Now I setted up a onItemClickListner with that I get the imageID -> this works!. Now I'd like to search my DB with that imageID, but it allways returns "null", but that shouldn't be because if filled my DB exactly with those imageID's.
The Structure of the Table is that: RowID | SOURCE | INFO
In Info i stored the imageID's

**Question**

---

How do I have to change Cursor that I can get the entries over INFO.
Down here you find the Code of my Cursor:

**Code:**

---

```
    //Es wird nach der ID des smiley gesucht.
    public Cursor getSmiley(String info) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

        this.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { INFO, SOURCE,
                }, INFO + "=" + info, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

**How I get the imageID-back**

---

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(SFilterConfigActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    //Hier wird herrausgefunden welche ID das Bild hat und in den jeweiligen String gespeichert
    source = String.valueOf(v.getId());
    Log.v("IMAGEID", source);
    SmileyHelper.open();

    Cursor c = SmileyHelper.getSmiley(source);
    startManagingCursor(c);

        if (c != null){
            String size = String.valueOf(c.getCount());
            Log.v("WhatsInC", size);
        }


    if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
        do { 
        text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.SOURCE));
        Log.v("WHATINTEXT", text);
        smiley = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.INFO)); 
        Log.v("WHATINSMILEY", smiley);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    SmileyHelper.close();
```

---

**Additional Information:**

1. WhatIsInC, returns "0".

If you need more Code, just tell me
Thx for your help in advance!
Best Regards
safari

Comment: i changed it, but its still null... execute is undefined.. :(

Comment: but than i have to delete the cursor right? Because this is void.

Comment: I get the data that is in the database, but it just dosen't search out the row, probably something with the gridview is wrong..

Comment: no, in your query mentioned above in question, this.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { INFO, SOURCE,
                }, INFO + "=" + info, null, null, null, null, null);
what is the "true" parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Cursor getEmpByDept(String Dept)
  {
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
   String [] columns=new String[]{"_id",colName,colAge,colDeptName};
   Cursor c=db.query(viewEmps, columns, colDeptName+"=?", 
    new String[]{Dept}, null, null, null);
   return c;
  }
```

The db.query has the following parameters:

```
 1.String Table Name: The name of the table to run the query against
 2.String [ ] columns: The projection of the query, i.e., the columns to retrieve
 3.String WHERE clause: where clause, if none pass null
 4.String [ ] selection args: The parameters of the WHERE clause
 5.String Group by: A string specifying group by clause
 6.String Having: A string specifying HAVING clause
 7.String Order By by: A string Order By by clause
```

So, in your query,

```
this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { INFO, SOURCE },INFO + " = '" + info + "'" , null, null, null, null, null);
```

or

```
this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] {INFO, SOURCE},INFO + " = ?",new String[]
{info},null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I changed it, but I still get "null" is it possible that it has todo something with the onItemClickListner..

Comment: i putted the hardcode values in the if, but I get null too. So probably the If isn't working.. btw. it also dosn't give out my Log.v's in the if.

Comment: what? I am debugging it with logcat.

Comment: I don't have c.count() in it.