# Android SQLite - Why is Column's string returning 'null'?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my database:

```
private static Database mInstance;
String str;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tasks";
protected static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
protected static final String COLUMN_TASK = "task_name";
protected static final String COLUMN_EXP = "exp_rate";


private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " 
                            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID 
                            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                            + COLUMN_TASK + " TEXT, "+ COLUMN_EXP +" TEXT);"; 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tasks.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

I need to get this value: 'COLUMN_EXP' of id. But with this code 'null' getting.

```
    public void getTaskExp(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
            COLUMN_TASK , COLUMN_EXP }, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXP));
    }
     Log.v("hex", "str is " + str);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Where is the error I'm doing? Please help me. Thanks. Sorry my bad English.

Comment: Try cursor.getString(2)

Comment: You have added data to the database table right?

Comment: One more question - have you added the `exp_rate` column to the table later than the other columns? If that is the case you will need to increment the database version to force update to add the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is data in the table. Also you can try checking for null in the column.

something like,

```
if(str != null){
  Log.v("hex", "str is " + str);

}
```

If it persists, check this out. [SQLite Query returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754146/sqlite-query-returns-null)